# ViewDidLoad method doesnt keep a variable?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

**Here is my question:**

In the `viewDidLoad` method I create a variable using `NSUserDefaults` (if its the "first run" I create it and fill it with `NSNumber`. Then I try to use it in another method and ... nothing. It looks like its empty.  **Anyone can help me?** Lot of Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"seriesBool"]!=nil)

{
    seriesBool = [defaults objectForKey:@"seriesBool"];

}

else

{
    int i;

    seriesBool = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:9];

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)

    {
       [seriesBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    }

}


-(IBAction)toAction:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"array: %@", seriesBool);
}
```

seriesBool is empty...

Comment: I think it doesn't matter in this case. Since he's not using a strong property neither retaining the iVar, the iVar is being released.

Comment: @BrunoKoga How do you know he's not using `strong`?

Comment: did u write [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]; ? otherwise it wont store your value in nsuserdefaults. you must have to write that.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set properties like

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray * seriesBool;
```

and use it

self.seriesBool = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:9];

or

use

```
 seriesBool = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];
```

instead of

```
seriesBool = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:9];
```

&  u have to  alloc and assign the object

```
seriesBool = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
seriesBool = [defaults objectForKey:@"seriesBool"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn first the basics of Memory Management. What's happening there is, basically, that you're not retaining the seriesBool iVar.

Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Try to retain your iVar or, better, create a strong/retain property and use the accessor methods.

Comment: True. I didn't retain it. I thought when you write the property in the interface: @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *seriesBool; it´s already retained. But it's not. Thanks all for the answer. I will study this guide first ;)